# How to make dropdown arrow appear again after selecting?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

my problem is that the arrow in the dropdown disappears after an option in the dropdown has been selected. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you for all answers.

Before selecting:

[image]

After selecting:

[image]

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <hr>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
            Select Pre-Processing Method <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
          <li><a href="#">Normalisation</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Histogram Equalisation</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>

          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Hover me for more options</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a href="#">Even More..</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML code

Comment: or jsfiddle example

Comment: I added a HTML code. Hope that is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace the dropdown text with the text of the item selected by the user, including the caret, you can try the following.

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
    var link = $(this);
    // You can remove these two lines if you don't want to mark
    // the selected item as active in the dropdown menu
    link.closest('ul').find('li.active').removeClass('active');
    link.parent().addClass('active');

    var dropdown = link.closest('.dropdown').find('#dLabel');
    dropdown.html($(this).html() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

Here is a **Bootply**
http://www.bootply.com/72qTbDbEC0

Comment: @matchifang  You bet. Glad I could help.